# Как в Python добиться, чтобы генератор списка создавал все члены типа array модуля Numpy?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Имею список (столбец) `y_i_list` со значениями `y`:

```
y_i_list = [0.0, 0.3090169943749474, 0.5877852522924731, ... 1.2246467991473532e-16]
```

Далее я вычитаю из второго члена первый, из третьего - второй и так далее. Получаю новый столбец. В нем проделываю ту же операцию и проч. В результате на основе исходного списка получаю столбцы с конечными разностями.

На выходе у меня некий новый список с вложенными в него списками-столбцами:

```
[[0.0,
  0.3090169943749474,
  0.5877852522924731,
  ...
  1.2246467991473532e-16],
 array([ 0.30901699, ... -0.27876826, -0.30901699]),...]
```

В этом новом списке - все столбики, начиная с исходного. Проблема, что исходный столбец получается не типа `array`. А надо, чтобы этот тип носили все столбцы (вложенные списки значений). Как этого добиться?

Код:

```
y_i_list = [0.0, 0.3090169943749474, 0.5877852522924731, 0.8090169943749475, 0.9510565162951535, 1.0, 0.9510565162951536, 0.8090169943749475, 0.5877852522924732, 0.3090169943749475, 1.2246467991473532e-16]

# ниже в строке наличие нуля в np.arange(0, len(y_i_list)
# определяет, что в итоговом списке получаем столбцы начиная с исходного 
# (возьмем единицу, и исходный будет отсутствовать)
result = [ np.diff(y_i_list, d) for d in np.arange(0, len(y_i_list)) ] 
print(result)
```

Comment: `list(np.diff(y_i_list, d))` ?

Comment: Перед началом `y_i_list = np.array(y_i_list)`.